# Does brownie have functionality to analyze gas costs for all function calls?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, gas-estimate, brownie

Does brownie have any sort of functionality that gives a breakdown of the cost to deploy all contracts and execute all function calls within a brownie project with min, max and average gas cost statistics?